# Rails - How do you render the html version of a view in one link, and the json.builder version in another link?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, json, routes

I am fairly new to Ruby on Rails but I have been dabbling at a toy app (Practice Management), for practice.

I was able to render a fullcalendar-rails version of my appointments successfully for one link(using appointments_path, and a .json.jbuilder file). However, I now want a list version of the appointments index in html format but I can't seem to find an answer online.
I still want to use the same path (appointments_path), and the same information but with a different format.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Here is my code:

appointments_controller.rb

```
def index     
  @appointments = Appointment.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json
    format.html
  end
end
```

index.json.jbuilder

```
json.array! @appointments do |appointment|
  json.start appointment.starts_at
  json.title appointment.patient.initials
  json.url edit_appointment_url(appointment.id)
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<div class="appointments-index" id="appointments-index-body">
  <% if current_user.appointments.empty? %>
    You have no scheduled appointments.
  <% else %>
    <div id='appointments' class="appointments-body">
    <div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

After implementing appointments_path(format: :json) to either the link for a simple list or the fullcalendar-rails, I got this:

```
[{"start":"2014-02-13T14:45:00.000Z","title":"Beast,   A.","url":"http://localhost:3000/appointments/112/edit"},{"start":"2014-02- 
            13T16:00:00.000Z","title":"Beast,    A.","url":"http://localhost:3000/appointments/113/edit"},  {"start":"2014-02-13T15:00:00.000Z","title":"Beast,   A.","url":"http://localhost:3000/appointments/114/edit"},{"start":"2014-02-  13T15:15:00.000Z","title":"Beast, A.","url":"http://localhost:3000/appointments/115/edit"},  {"start":"2014-02-18T10:15:00.000Z","title":"Beast,   A.","url":"http://localhost:3000/appointments/116/edit"},{"start":"2014-02- 13T11:00:00.000Z","title":"Beast, A.","url":"http://localhost:3000/appointments/117/edit"}]
```

providing the id='appointments' in the  after else makes sure that fullcalendar-rails will be applied in this div.
Please let me know if there's any info I could add to make this clearer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can specify format in url helper, like this:

```
appointments_path(format: :json)
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!
Unfortunately, I got a weird output after following the above solution. Will post it shortly.

Comment: I actually misunderstood my dilemma here. The above code is working perfectly fine and the formatting has no problems whatsoever.

What I wanted to achieve was rendering a different view with the same information and I should create a new route and action for that instead.

Comment: It seems that I have not understood your idea correctly. Do you want to render just a plain html list with information about your appointments?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Just add an additional route and action for this.